# Maven profile file activation fails

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have a parent pom which defines profiles which shall be activated, when the defined folder exists:

```
<groupId>common</groupId>
<artifactId>common-build</artifactId>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dependency-profile-ejb</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}/src/profile/dependency-ejb/</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>[...]</dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dependency-profile-jsf</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}/src/profile/dependency-jsf/</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>[...]</dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have a maven project with several submodules:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-build</artifactId>
</parent>

<groupId>project/groupId>
<artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>project-child-one<module>
</modules>
```

In the child project I just define the parent dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-child-one</artifactId>
```

and in this child project I have defined the folder `src/profile/dependency-ejb`.

If I run the build of the projects in eclipse everything works as expected. I have then installed the project in jenkins, but the build fails. If I checkout the `project-parent` into a clean directory and try to run a maven build, the build fails, too.

Why does the build run in eclipse but not in command line? Why is the profile definition in the parent pom of `common-build` not respected?

Comment: Hello, can you try with `${project.basedir}` instead of `${basedir}` ?

Comment: Running `mvn -X ...` might give insights in such cases what really happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further tests I found the solution. The build failed, because the folders for the profile activation were missing. I have added the project to git and forgot that git does not commit/push empty folders.

The solution is to add an empty `.gitkeep` in the folders to force git to commit/push them.